# Visual Studio Code: Failed to save: Unable to write file

Tags: visual-studio-code, codespaces

I'm learning how to programm using the Visual Studio Code, but after a while a error pops up saying "Failed to save 'agree.c': Unable to write file". How can I solve it?

I have tried to refresh the page and then it works but after a while the error appears again.

[First error message that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbNPi.png)

[Unable to read file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIntD.png)

[error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXJ0t.png)

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio Code? Or what is Virtual Studio Code?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the page"?

Comment: Visual Studio Code (my mistake). I'm using it associated to the github so when it stops working I have been refreshing the browser page and then it works again for a while, but the error appears again and again

Comment: You can do a lot of stuff with Visual Studio Code, When you do not show what your are actually doing, it is almost impossible to help.   Also "Unable to write file"  is that error in your browser, or in vscode ?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the error. I'm using windows and the error appears in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Added [tag:codespaces] (which I do know noting about... )

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).